# How to load image dynamically in apex

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am taking one image tag in apex and i want to assign image to it from Static resource.

```
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.ABC, '/{!XYZMap[klmWrapper].wrapItem.item__r.Name__c}')}" width="50" height="50" />
```

and following part contains image name which is stored in static resource.

```
'/{!XYZMap[klmWrapper].wrapItem.item__r.Name__c}'
```

when above link prints it gives me image name but when i put it in apex url it does not replace it with image name. It considers that as String. 
Help me with this.